# Why is my array printing all zeroes and not all of the integers in a range?

Tags: java, arrays

Array `a` is printing all zeroes, whereas it should print the values of `i` (which are all of the integers from `m` to `n`, both also integers)

```
System.out.println("\n enter the values of m and n");
int m,n,i,j=0;
int[] a=new int[100]; 
m=in.nextInt();
n=in.nextInt();
for(i=m;i<=n;i++)
{
    a[j]=i;//array a is storing the value of i
    j++;
    System.out.println(a[j]);//printing array a
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(a[j++]);`

Answer (score 6):

That is because you increase the value of `j` before you print it, and the next element still is `0`.

Put `j++` after the print statement.